# Storyboard help, Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode

I accidentally created my UI in the LaunchScreen.storyboard, and I understand how big of a mistake this was since you cant dynamically change a launchscreen. So I was wondering if I can just create a new storyboard and somehow add the UI I already created to that new storyboard or will I have to remake it? Total noob mistake I know, but I will appreciate any help I can get. Thanks.

Comment: You can copy/paste items (controllers, views etc) between storyboards or even duplicate and rename your storyboard.

Comment: Copying entire scenes should work well, but coping views won't preserve the AutoLayout constraints, which is a major pain.

Comment: Maybe rename your Main storyboard -> temp, then  LaunchScreen -> Main,, and then temp -> Launchscreen.

Answer (score 0):

You can normally copy or cut your controllers in the LaunchScreen.storyboard and paste them directly into Main.storyboard. If you no longer have the Main.storyboard, you can add a new file one with command n